# PS script looking for files in wrong folder

Tags: powershell, csv, import

For some reason, even though I specify the `$inputfolder` I get an error in the script saying it was looking for `[the target file from the $inputfolder]` but in the folder where the script is located. I don't understand why. Thanks.

```
$inputfolder = 'C:\path\to\file\'
$inputobject = Get-ChildItem $inputfolder
$outputpath = Join-Path $inputfolder 'dundada.csv'

Import-Csv $inputobject | select column1 | Export-Csv -Path $outputpath -NoTypeInformation
```

This is the error I get:

```
Import-Csv : Could not find file 'C:\path\to\folder\containing\PS\script\Target_File_from_Input_Folder.csv'.
```

Comment: Your *inputfolder* path and path displayed in Error message seems different.

Comment: @dhilmathy yes that is my confusion, I hardcoded the variable for `@inputfolder` in my script, but the error is because it is looking for the target file in the script's folder.. I have no idea why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that what you supplied to the cmdlet here:

```
Import-Csv $inputobject
```

is only `filename.csv` which means PowerShell looks for the file in your current folder. If you want to specify literal path you have to use

```
Import-Csv $inputobject.FullName
```

Why is that? PowerShell tries to somehow translate the value you provided to the parameter it wants. In that case it tries to translate to string using `.ToString()` and supplies it to `-LiteralPath` (as it's the only [required parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6#required-parameters)).

Comment: Thank you! I was getting a headache.

Answer (score -1):

I think the $inputobject = Get-ChildItem $inputfolder doesnt get the filename but the dir structure of the input folder. Maybe try

```
$inputobject = Get-ChildItem $inputfolder -Name *.csv
```

Assuming there is only one csv file in the inputfolder

Comment: This will still fail.  He needs the `FullName` attribute off the `FileInfo` object.

Comment: It worked for me :) Here is a snippet 
`PS C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads> $inputobject = Get-ChildItem $inputfolder -Name *.csv
PS C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads> **$inputobject**
SalesJan2009.csv
PS C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads> Import-Csv $inputobject |select Country

Country
-------
United Kingdom
United States
United States
Australia
United States
United States`